# Vite build issue: manifest.json not found in hosted Laravel 10 app

Tags: laravel, vite

I just hosted a Laravel 10 app that uses TailwindCSS and Vite to bundle assets. When I use `npm run build` locally everything works well, but when I host the application, I change my project structure. Now the application can't find the `manifest.json` file.

Below are images of my hosted project structure:

[image: structure]

[image: public_html folder]

[image: project code]

this is the `vite.conf` file:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

[This is a link to the website](https://torrymeshares.com/dashboard).

This is the code I used to call vite in my `app.blade.php` file:

```
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

[image: error]

I modified the `vite.conf` file with this:

```
build: {
    manifest: true,
    outDir: './build',
},
```

I checked multipple resources online and changed the `.htaccess` file and notice that the problem wasn't there.